# Looking for a phrase to replace "it is noteworthy"

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms

I am looking for a phrase to interchangeably use with "it is noteworthy that" or "it is critical to note that".

The phrase will be used in a math paper to grab the attention of readers at specific parts of the text. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just "Please note ..."

Comment: So you do not expect your paper's audience to be able to appreciate by themselves which parts are noteworthy?  Your writing will be much stronger if you can make the noteworthy parts evident to the intended audience without relying on such props.

Comment: Not clear from the question what is wrong with the original phrases and therefore what will be considered a "correct" answer. Also this appears to be a writing advice request (off topic).

Comment: Importantly, / Crucially,.

Comment: N.B. or N.b. or n.b. (an abbreviation for nota bene in latin which means literally "note well"). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota_bene  In some contexts it is also trendy to write: "Pro tip" or "Fun fact". In the middle ages people also used: "the abbreviation D.M. from Dignum memoria (Worth remembering), or (3) a symbol of a little hand (☞), called a manicule, with the index finger pointing towards the beginning of the significant passage."

Answer (score 3):

You can use ***Please note that*** or ***be advised that.***

Regarding their difference:

> These two clauses mean basically the same thing: the reader or
>   listener is being informed of something. The verb *note* in your first
>   example is used in the sense of "take notice of." Similarly, *be
>   advised* means "be informed or apprised." In both cases, the speaker or
>   writer communicates a fact or situation. The difference lies in the
>   level of language: *be advised* that is rather formal and is often
>   encountered in commercial and legal contexts, while *please note that*
>   is more informal. [(source)](https://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/bien-well/fra-eng/proverbes-proverbs/notez-note-eng.html)

Comment: Although both of these could be used as you suggest in a general sense, the latter is not appropriate for a formal paper, which is the OP's target.  The former is at best marginal for such a context.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the following props:

---

- It is important to note/state/declare/define...
- It is worth noting that ...
- It should be noted/stated/considered/more discussed/...
- It is critical/important to consider/take/note/state/...
- It is critical/important/necessary to state ...
- It is worth considering/noting/...
- It is highly desirable/important/... to consider/note/take... that ...

Comment: It was very difficult to parse this answer. Please consider separating examples more clearly. Also, many of the words you give as examples are unrelated to the user's question--for example, "it is important to define ..." is not related to the question.